# Pagination with recursion while using loadModel

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my "Reports" controller, which is just a dummy controller without any actual database, I'm trying to generate a paginated view of other models. For example, to generate paginated view of "Transactions" model I'm doing the following:

```
$this->loadModel('Transactions');
$this->Transactions->bindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Item'=>array('className'=>'Item'),'Member'=>array('className'=>'Member'))));
$results = $this->paginate('Transactions',null,array('recursive'=>1));
```

But this is not giving me associated data from Items and Members. If I do a

```
$this->Transactions->find('all',array('recursive'=>1))
```

I get the associated data, but not paginated. How will I get paginated view which includes the associated data too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: First, even when plural model names can work for some odd reason, the convention is that model names are singular, like `$this->loadModel('Transaction');`. See [the manual on naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions).

Second, forget about `recursive` and go for the `Containable` behavior. Frankly, it's so useful that I wonder why it isn't the default process (perhaps because Containable got created when the framework was very mature).  Matt has [a good book](http://www.pseudocoder.com/blog/free-cakephp-e-book-super-awesome-advanced-cakephp-tips) explaining why Containable is good (download it, really, it's almost mandatory :D ). But to help even more, I'm going to tell you exactly how you solve your issue with containable:

1) Define the associations in the models, like:

In Transaction model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'className' => 'Item',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
    )
);
```

In Item model:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Transaction' => array(
        'className' => 'Transaction',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'exclusive' => true,
    )
);
```

Do the same for the Member model.

2) Create an `app_model.php` file in `/app/` with this code:
(The `$actsAs` variable here within the AppModel class tells all models to use Containable)

```
<?php
class AppModel extends Model {
    var $recursive = -1;
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
?>
```

3) In the Reports Controller, change the code to something like this:
(The contain parameter is an array of all the associated models that you want to include. You can include only one assoc. model, or all, or whatever you want).

```
$this->loadModel('Transaction');
$this->paginate = array('Transaction' => array('contain' => array('Item', 'Member')));      
$results = $this->paginate('Transaction');
```

And that's it!

Comment: Holy sh**. Such a simple mistake! I've been using Cake from two years, and I couldn't spot that I'm using plural instead of singular for the model name!! I'm breaking my head from yesterday on why it wasn't working.

@YOMorales, thanks for your time. You've really got a sharp eye :) And I know about Containable, I tried that too before posting here. I agree to what you said, that containable is better practice. I've been using cake before it hit v1, long before it got containable, I guess old habits die hard :D

Comment: Cool! I've been using Cake since then too! It's good to talk with a long-time user. Anyway, the weird thing is that plural model names DO work for the example code you gave. Weird, yes.

Comment: All of Matt's links seem to be broken lately.  Does anybody know a working link for that e-book?

Comment: Here is a new link: http://www.pseudocoder.com/Super_Awesome_Advanced_CakePHP_Tips.pdf